# Where to find the API logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm using an API that has in the source code this line:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

No other configuration methods regarding this logger. As such, I would assume that the .log file would be located in the module's folder after running the script, with the name of the module file. However I do not find anything like this so I cannot really read the logs. Is there a way to know where is this log file being saved, or at least to override the path to choose it myself?

Thanks

Comment: Unless the logger is configured for some handler, there's no file to be saved and the output doesn't probably even go to the console.

Comment: Is there a way I can create a file that will record all the logs that are using the `logger` instance? thanks

Comment: Have you checked the Python [logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging)?

Comment: Yes of course I have, but I wasn't able to find any example of using a `.getLogger()` instance together with `.basicConfig()` method to create that file, and anything I've tried so far (some random combinations) didn't give me any result.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a file manually. For example:

```py
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log')
```

To learn how `logging` works check the official HOWTO: https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that when creating a log from scratch. However in this case the API uses by default an instance of a Logger (called logger in the code as you can see in the OC) and logs everything into it. Basically the API code is logging everything into the logger, for instance `logger.info(msg)` but is not creating any file. I just need to tell the script "Create that log file and put it on the same folder as the module" so I can check it afterwards. Any ideas? Thanks